# ASP.NET MVC: How to include PartialView in custom html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

I have TinyMCE editor in my custom site CMS and store HTML content in SQL DB.

Then I render it in cshtml RazorView:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Content)
```

How can I include PartialView inside html content by TinyMCE?

Something like:

```
...content html...
<div>[[ViewName]]</div>
...content html...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial view can be included in an HTML page by using the following

`<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Folder/ViewName.ascx");%>`

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the Partial View and set the resultant html as the content for TinyMCE.

```
private string ProduceViewResult(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;

  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.ToString();
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var partialViewHtml = ProduceViewResult("PartialViewName", myModel);
```